# HTML not displaying correctly in some e-mail clients

Tags: html, email

I've got this HTML that is sent in an email but some receivers experience problems in their email client (I suspect outlook).

I've checked and re-checked this HTML code over and over but I can't find the reason why some elements aren't on the right position so I could use some help.

I've highlighted the "errors" with dark red lines:

[image: buggy mail]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>'.$mail['subject'].'</title>
</head>

<body>
<table style="border: 0; border-spacing: 0; line-height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 559px;">
    <tr style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <td colspan="5" style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 559px;"><img src="'.$root.$cards['path']['mail'].'0-0-'.$mail['card'].'.jpg" style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;" alt="" /></td>
    </tr><tr style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <td style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 120px;"><img src="'.$root.$cards['path']['mail'].'1-0.jpg" style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;" alt="" /></td>
        <td rowspan="2"  style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; vertical-align: top; width: 210px"><p style="border: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px; margin: 0; padding: 0; word-wrap: break-word; width: 210px;">'.$mail['message'].'<br /><br />'.$mail['from_name'].'</p></td>
        <td colspan="3" style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 269px;"><img src="'.$root.$cards['path']['mail'].'1-2.jpg" style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;" alt="" /></td>
    </tr><tr style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <td style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 120px;"><img src="'.$root.$cards['path']['mail'].'2-0.jpg" style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;" alt="" /></td>
        <td style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 65px;"><img src="'.$root.$cards['path']['mail'].'/2-2.jpg" style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;" alt="" /></td>
        <td style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; vertical-align: top; width: 170px;"><p style="border: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; margin: 0; line-height: 12px; padding: 0; width: 170px;">'.$mail['to_name'].'</p></td>
        <td style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 34px;"><img src="'.$root.$cards['path']['mail'].'2-4.jpg" style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;" alt="" /></td>
    </tr><tr style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <td colspan="5" style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 559px;"><img src="'.$root.$cards['path']['mail'].'3-0.jpg" style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;" alt="" /></td>
    </tr><tr style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <td colspan="5" style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 559px;"><p style="border: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px; margin: 0; padding: 0; word-wrap: break-word; width: 210px;"><a href="http://www.geschiedeniszeeland.nl" target="_blank"><img src="'.$root.'images/site-button.jpg" style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;" alt="" /></a></p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

don't worry about the bits of PHP in the HTML because that works like a charm.

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it's going to be something subtle. It would be easier to figure out if we were looking at precisely the HTML and not PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all whenever you use an img tag you must use style="display:block" - this is to avoid   the 1px white line beneath the image.

Second of all it's better to use tabel in tabel rather than collspan/rowspan.

I can also see that you have a 559pw with tabel but your 3th line is: 120+65+170+34=389 px, and you're also missing a column.

Comment: I've changed the images to block and fixed the row width you mentioned. The source code is going back to the customer which wants to upload it themselves (god knows why) so I'll just have to wait. If it did fix the problem I'll be very happy. Thanks in advance!